# Calculate 2D Effective mass from bulk effective mass

Tags: mass, semiconductor-physics, computational-physics, density-of-states

I am trying to create a self consistent Shrodinger Poisson Solver for various semiconductors. There is already one done by Professor Hu from UC Berkeley - [QM CV Simulator](http://www-device.eecs.berkeley.edu/qmcv/).

Looking at the code, they have used different values of effective mass when calculating 2D density of states compared to bulk effective mass. Can you tell me how can I calculate these 2D effective mass values from bulk effective mass?

The relevant codes can be found in the shelec.m and shhole.m files. I have included the codes here for convenience.

From shhole.m-

```
hb= 1.05459E-27;   % Plank's constant in ergs
m0 = 9.109534E-28; % electron mass in g

m1 = 0.291;        % Electron mass in z direction for heavy hole
m2 = 0.2;          % Electron mass in z direction for light hole
m3 = 0.29;         % Electron mass in z direction for split off

md1 = 0.645;       % Density of state mass for haevy hole
md2 = 0.251;       % Density of state mass for light hole
md3 = 0.29;        % Density of state mass for sprit-off band

deltaE=0.044;      % spin-orbit sprit energy

g1 = 1;            % degeneracy for heavy hole 
g2 = 1;            % degeneracy for light hole
g3 = 1;            % degeneracy for split off band


%****************density of state     ****************
Do1 = g1*md1*m0/3.1415/(hb)^2/6.24146E11; %density of state (#/eV/cm2)
Do2 = g2*md2*m0/3.1415/(hb)^2/6.24146E11; %density of state (#/eV/cm2)
Do3 = g3*md3*m0/3.1415/(hb)^2/6.24146E11; %density of state (#/eV/cm2)
```